# HTML markup validator -alert duplicate attributes- in VS Code

Tags: html, visual-studio, refactoring, visual-studio-code

Is there a plugin or factory settings to alert duplicates in HTML attributes in the Code editor VisualStudio?.

To check:

- Initial spaces,
- Attributes duplicates.

As a refactor...

Something similar as VisualStudio-Community, which does.
**I.e:**
[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [HTMLHint Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mkaufman.HTMLHint) with [attr-no-duplication rule](https://github.com/yaniswang/HTMLHint/wiki/attr-no-duplication) to check for duplicate attributes.

Comment: I got it yesterday.. And mark as correct for others. Thank you!.